# Use Firebase In-App-Messaging in Expo Project

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to add in a built-in application with react-native-expo a series of tools from firebase. I managed to add the following features Cloud Messaging and Firebase Analytics. But I have to integrate In-app-messaging and Dynamic links, too.

First time I install all firebase module/dependencies to do this task.

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.3",
"@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^12.9.3",
```

and my file looks like:

```
.......
import inAppMessaging from '@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging
.......
useEffect(()=>{
   await inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(true);
}[])
```

but I get a warning:

> Unhandled promise rejection: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()

After that I try to find a solution,I learn that expo allow to create plugins to extend expo functionality.

I try to solve problem following this [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/), but I couldn't figure out how to create these plugins.

Next I find a module that can help me [with-rn-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/with-rn-firebase)  but is not working and the module is deprecated.

Then I searched the internet until I discovered other people with the same problem [this is the link](https://fantashit-com.translate.goog/error-cannot-find-module-fs-promises/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ro&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=nui,op,sc) I see in their `app.json` a basic config of plugin and I try to implement in my project,after I install dependencies that I need to add in my file:

```
"plugins": [
    "@react-native-firebase/app",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging"
  
],
```

But I get an error:

> Package "@react-native-firebase/analytics" does not contain a valid config plugin.
> Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin
> Cannot use import statement outside a module

What I mean is, if anyone has ever faced this problem, I want in my project to be able to use in-app-messaging and dynamic-links if someone has tried an implementation with expo and has any idea

Comment: I find the solution,expo build:android took onli js file but not file from directory like android/ios,ia manage to solve this problem using  eas,fallowing command: eas init,eas prebuild --android,and evrithing is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved the problem,expo when I use the command **expo:build** android it only compiles my javascript files,but some of the code was written in java and other optional files in the android / ios folder.So instead of compiling with **expo** I used **eas**.
Faloowing command:

Run as administrator cmd and write this line `npm install -g eas-cli`.

Initialize new module in your expo/react native project with this line `eas init`.

Build aplication using this line for android: `eas build --platform android`

*For ios is a bit different you mast edit your file `eas.json`:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.43.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Build aplication using this line for ios: `eas build --platform ios`

Eas build include in complile all app file .gradle/.js/.java/.xml/.m/.h and this thing offer your posibility to build mobile app in expo with same functionality and complexity like react native cli.

Usefull Link

https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

[React Native Expo Build Failing due to cocoapods version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120883/react-native-expo-build-failing-due-to-cocoapods-version)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run locally using expo dev client

https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/

Mostly, the package that is not supported by expo can run natively. But you need successfully built in eas build.