# React Native Expo Build Failing due to cocoapods version

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to run a building Expo but keep running into an error due to outdated Cocoapods.

```
    [!] `RNFBApp` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.2`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.1`.
    Error: Your project requires a newer version of CocoaPods, you can update it in the build profile in eas.json by either:
     - changing the current version under key "cocoapods"
     - switching to an image that supports that version under key "image"
```

I have tried to update my eas file with the version I want as per the instructions, but it is simply ignored it seems :/

```
    {
      "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.38.1"
      },
      "build": {
        "development": {
          "distribution": "internal",
          "android": {
            "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
          },
          "ios": {
            "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
            "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
          }
        },
        "preview": {
          "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "production": {}
      },
      "submit": {
        "production": {}
      }
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this? My build runs fine locally and loads up on the simulator no worries.

Answer (score 3):

Since I've managed to go over this issue I'll share my story:

I'm running the following command on Windows:

`eas build --profile release --platform ios`

And here's relevant part of my eas.json:

```
  {
    "build": {
      "release": {
        "android": {
          "buildType": "app-bundle",
          "gradleCommand": ":app:bundleRelease"
        },
        "ios": {
          "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Adding cocoapods key to eas.json fixed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all you have to do is replace your code with it and everything will work fine.

```
{
  "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.38.3"
   },
   "build": {
         "development": {
             "distribution": "internal",
          "android": {
              "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
           },
           "ios": {
               "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
                "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
           }
     },
    "preview": {
         "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
       "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
     }
    }
 },
  "submit": {
     "production": {}
  }
}
```

You need to add this code to the **production** inside the **build**

```
 "ios": {
     "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
   }
```

[image]